# How do you merge 2 Pandas dataframes on 1 column so all columns are included & any missing index observations included too?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have 2 Pandas dataframes like the below, how do I merge them on the Person column so that all columns are included in the merge and the observations are matched to the index(Person)? I don't want any of the index observations dropped and would like to have all columns populated(or blank if NaN).

df1

```
Person,Age,Hair
Derrick,22,Short
Nick,23,Long
Christian,24,NaN
```

df2

```
Person,Height,Eyes
Keenan,62,NaN
Nick,63,Green
Christian,64,Blue
Terry,58, Brown
Anthony,61,Brown
```

Comment: Can you post the code of it? It would be easy to try it out.

Comment: `df1.merge(df2, on='Person', how='outer')`? You can read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101, and if so I'll close as a dup.

Comment: Thank you, yes. Please feel free to close. That helped me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)